# FPS is ~60 even when there is no interaction on the table view

Tags: ios, iphone, rendering, frame-rate, battery

I've tab bar based app, on each tab we've a table view, i'm facing problem with my app draining battery.

So when checking the FPS of each screen, all screens FPS drop to zero when there are no interactions, but on home feed alone after fetching second page info the FPS is constantly showing ~60 even when there is no change in rendering is needed.

Shouldn't the FPS drop when there is no necessity for no rendering update on screen?

Answer (score 0):

My response is somewhere between a comment and an answer.

Are you re-rendering static updates? Your app may be re-drawing the same figure each time, making it appear static. Also, you may be forcing a re-rendering by executing some update API even though you haven't executing any drawing APIs. You can check by placing some checking code before each possible API that might force a re-rendering and logging calls.

Comment: actually there was an activity indicator we use in paginate, which is rendering. which is causing the FPS.